# Make low resolution image larger size

Tags: image, testing, image-processing, automated-tests

There is an 380x380 resolution png image with 980 bites size. What I need is the same resolution and extension image but with size more than 1Mb. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, but I need to save extension. It has to be png.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem - why do you need to increase the filesize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PNG is a lossless compression format. If your image is e.g. all white, it compresses to very small size.

You should fill the image with random pixels. But even then, the largest size you will get will be 600 kB (380 * 380 * 4 bytes per pixel).

The PNG format also allows appending any data after the file, so you could e.g. add 1 MB of zeroes to the end of your file.